# Check Active Directory without password in Express js

Tags: node.js, npm, active-directory, ldap, passport.js

I am using `express js 4.1`. I want to access the Active directory without user and admin credentials. I would simply wants to check username alone connected in the root domain. If the user exists in the domain, i will redirect my application to main page from login page. I have tried out with most of the npm's such that `activedirectory`, `passport-windowsauth`, `passport-ldapauth`

None of the above methods is working as they all requires credential details of either admin or user at some point. Please suggest me a good way to access active directory with username alone and npm absolutely suits my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Active Directory cannot be accessed anonymously.  Such access as what you are looking for will not work, you must bind with full credentials, for every type of user authentication, whether it is with an individual, or some other known account.

Comment: Did you mean username and password is must for all types of authentication? If we want to access all users, we can commonly have root password (in my case it is a password of one of the user in my domain connected) to access domain. Is this way is appreciable?